# JAXB marshalling into HTML table via XSLT contains empty values

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, jaxb

I am trying to emulate table generation via xslt. I have these two class models.

Table entry contains rows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "table")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "header", "rows" })
public class TableEntry extends PropertyEntry {

    private String header;

    private final List<TableRowEntry> rows = new ArrayList<TableRowEntry>();

    @XmlElement(name = "row", required = true)
    public List<TableRowEntry> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

Then I have TableRowEntry model class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "tableRow")
public class TableRowEntry implements Reportable {

    private List<String> cells = new ArrayList<String>();

    @XmlElement(name = "cell")
    public List<String> getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public void setCells(List<String> cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }
}
```

and I have this in xsl template

```
<xsl:for-each select="table">
    <table>
        <xsl:if test="@header">
            <th><xsl:value-of select="@header"/></th>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
          <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="cell"/></td>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then I do this and I marshall it

```
TableEntry tableEntry = new TableEntry();
tableEntry.setHeader("This is my header");

TableRowEntry tableRow = new TableRowEntry();
tableRow.setCells(Arrays.asList("cell", "cell2", "cell3"));

TableRowEntry tableRow2 = new TableRowEntry();
tableRow2.setCells(Arrays.asList("cell4", "cell5", "cell6"));

tableEntry.getRows().add(tableRow);
tableEntry.getRows().add(tableRow2);
```

Whenever I marshall it into HTML, there are empty values in cells, why? When I marshall it into XML, these values in cells are there but I can not select that value in xsl template. Why?

There are two rows with three cells in each row in HTML file but these cells are empty.

I am using eclipse moxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to use this to pick that value:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
```